# French local returns "en"?

Tags: localization

I'm trying to check my craft locale to offer language switching but it seems that my french locale returns the "en" value???

When I run the following:
`{% if craft.locale == 'fr' %}`

I instead get the contents of:
`{% if craft.locale == 'en' %}`

Is anyone experiencing this? I don't see any code that could be messing with the code.

Note: the site url outputs just fine: `mysite.dev/fr/` BUT if I print `{{ craft.locale }}` I get "en".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably forgot to set the CRAFT_LOCALE constant for your French site in /fr/index.php, to tell Craft which locale's content to serve.

Comment: Yup... that was it! I completely forgot about those files! Thanks!